# Binding index value to event handler

Tags: javascript, closures, bind

Here my intent is to iterate over an array of elements, and set an event handler on each element while also binding the current iterator value to that event handler.  What I've come up with is:

```
for (var i = 0; i < elementArray.length; ++i)
{
      var elem = elementArray[i];
      elem.onmouseover = function() { foo(i); }
}

function foo(index)
{
       alert(index);
}
```

Here I use a closure to bind `i` to `foo`.  The problem is that when `foo` is actually invoked, `i` is always equal to `elementArray.length`, because of course, when `foo` is invoked `i` has already been incremented to the maximum value.  What I want here, I think, is for a new copy of `i` to be bound to each anonymous function, so that it passes the correct value to `foo`.  But I'm not sure what the best way to do this is.

Comment: No, you don't use a closure, or at least not enough of them :-) The `{ }` of the `for` loop do **not** create a new variable scope.  The only thing that does that in JavaScript is a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't working for you because by the time the `mouseover` handler is invoked, the value of `i` has changed, it is equal to `elementArray.length`. What you should do instead is return a function which creates a closure and holds the value of `i` at the time it is defined.

```
for (var i = 0; i < elementArray.length; ++i)
{
      var elem = elementArray[i];
      elem.onmouseover = foo(i);
}

function foo(index)
{
    return function(){
       alert(index);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (or define one for the browsers that do not support it) to avoid (explicit) closures. Then your calls would be written as:

```
elem.onmouseover = function(x) { foo(x); }.bind(this, i);
```